# Deleting removed dynamic data

Tags: php, html

Say, I am editing a profile of a user, with a **HTML** of something like this:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<?php
    $count = 0;
    foreach($fetchResult as $data){
?>
    <input type="text" name="data[<?php echo $count ?>][name]" value="<?php echo $data['Name'] ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="data[<?php echo $count ?>][id]" value="<?php echo $data['DataId']; ?>">
<?php
    $count++;
    }
?>
</form>
```

And I can add as many of this *(and delete)* dynamically *(adding of elements not included)*, but without the `hidden` input, because the `hidden` input will only appear during `foreach` of the data, and also new input does not really any id yet.

I managed to do the edit and insert part, with something like this:

```
foreach ($data as $datum) {
    if (empty($datum['id'])) {
        //insert the new inputs
    } else {
        //update the input
    }
}
```

I solved this before by just deleting the data and inserting again, but this can't be used if the data are connected to others in a database *(as a foreign key)*.

What other ways can be done to check if what `id`s are removed after submitting?

Comment: What exacly is your question? I didn't get it after reading it two times..

Comment: @DanielDäschle If the looped inputs are removed dynamically before submitting, how can I check/get the removed `id`s after submitting.